# Can I command CMake to not generate a Build system, but compile/link only?

Tags: cmake

I am working on a small-ish scale project.

```
Engine/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── game/
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── lib/
    ├── zlib/
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── DirectXTK/
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    └── libpng/
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

Is it possible to not generate build systems for everything whats under `lib/` and instead compile and link the library directly into the `Engine` project?

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
project(Engine VERSION 0.1)

add_subdirectory("./Game")
add_subdirectory("./Libraries/directxtk" "lib/directxtk")
add_subdirectory("./Libraries/zlib" "lib/zlib")
add_subdirectory("./Libraries/libzip" "lib/libzip")
target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

Visual Studio atleast generates a solution that contains several projects for every library;
I would like to have only `Game` within that solution and `Game` having all libraries linked instead.

Comment: One way or the other you'll need the dependencies for building your target. I cannot determine based on the info in the question, if delivering the binaries of the dependencies via archive or by just having them located in a directory after having built them on the same system is a viable option for you. Btw: CMake does not compile anything. The only thing cmake does is generate a build system (plus provide some convenience functionality for providing a platform independent command line interface); The actual compilation is done by the build system which is why you cannot skip this part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to not generate build systems for everything whats under lib/ and instead compile and link the library directly into the Engine project?

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What do you *really* want to do?

1. Are you trying to avoid CMake spending time configuring those projects? If they're really optional, then add `option()`s to disable them.
2. Are you spending a lot of time rebuilding everything when you only want some parts? Let me point you to the `cmake --build ... --config <Release|Debug|...> --target Game` command. That will build only what is needed for target `Game`.
3. Something else?

But this question of not "generat[ing] build systems" is ill-formed. CMake is a *build system generator*. How do you make a C++ compiler not compile C++?

Comment: I understand that cmake is a build system generator, but in my case zlib, libzip etc. are not really needed except for linking.

Comment: You cannot get from (e.g.) zlib sources to linking zlib without all of the necessary steps in between: which includes compiling and linking zlib, which has to be orchestrated by something... that something is a build system.

Comment: @Raildex you should use a dependency manager if you just want to link to existing libraries. Try `vcpkg`/`Conan`/`msys2`. Or if you are lucky enough to build on Ubuntu, just resort to system's package manager